# Select (invented values) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, grouping

I'm trying to set up a a single column table, that I can use for grouping later,
the idea is as follows:

```
select         ('Value1' , 'Value2') as ColumnName
```

in the and I should have something which looks like a table with one column, but doesn't really exist in my Data Warehouse,

```
 |ColumnName|
 |Value1    |
 |Value2    |
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try UNION:

```
SELECT 'Value1' as ColumnName
UNION
SELECT 'Value2' as ColumnName
```

Comment: and make sure the data types correspond. utilize cast([columnname] as type)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [table value constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx):

```
select *
from (values ('Value 1'), ('Value 2')) as T(ColumnName);
```

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11288).